# SQL Server: must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on SQL Server 2012. I try to declare two variables `@max` and `@rc` and use them in the insert statement:

```
DECLARE @max INT 
SET @max = 100000

DECLARE @rc INT
SET @rc = 1

INSERT INTO dbo.Nums VALUES(1);

WHILE @rc * 2 <= @max
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Nums 
       SELECT n + @rc 
       FROM dbo.Nums

    SET @rc = @rc * 2
END

INSERT INTO dbo.Nums 
   SELECT n + @rc 
   FROM dbo.Nums 
   WHERE n + @rc <= @max
GO
```

I get this error (four times):

> [Error Code: 137, SQL State: 37000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@rc".

When I try the following:

```
DECLARE @max INT
SET @max = 100000

DECLARE @rc INT
SET @rc = 1

INSERT INTO dbo.Nums VALUES(1);

WHILE @rc * 2 <= @max
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rc     INT
    DECLARE @max    INT

    SET @max = 100000

    INSERT INTO dbo.Nums 
       SELECT n + @rc 
       FROM dbo.Nums

    SET @rc = @rc * 2
END

INSERT INTO dbo.Nums 
   SELECT n + @rc 
   FROM dbo.Nums 
   WHERE n + @rc <= @max
GO
```

I only get it once:

> [Error Code: 137, SQL State: 37000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@rc".

Can you help me figure out the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you selecting all the lines of SQL to run? It runs fine for me and I think you're not selecting the lines that declare the variables when you're executing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use DbVisualizer to run the command. it does not allow selecting lines I put the whole code and simple execute it.

Comment: Must be a DbVisualizer quirk/problem.   Works fine in SSMS; there is nothing wrong with the SQL.

Comment: What version @TabAlleman. In 2008r2 it complains because the variables are declared inside the loop.

Comment: Try removing the semi-colon after INSERT INTO dbo.Nums VALUES(1). I tried in SQLFiddle and it gave me an error when using the semi-colon.

Comment: Oh, I was only looking at the first example.   Sorry.

Comment: And actually you can declare them inside the loop. However, in the second example they are declared twice which will never work. Not sure why you got the error message you got but the second example is just flat broken.

Comment: I use DbVisualizer  free 9.1.11 to accsee SQL 2012

Comment: That's why I suspect it's the client.   Looks like it's executing the script in multiple scopes/contexts, but I don't see enough evidence to deduce exactly where it changes to a new scope.

Comment: Removing the semi-colon fixed the "problem"? Your client tool is severely broken. See if there's a setting somewhere that allows you to specify a batch separator - seems the default is semi-colon, but IMHO you should make it `GO` to be consistent with native tools. The [last thing you should be doing is *removing* semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was dumbfounded by that as well, and I only discovered it because I tried to run it on SQLFiddle and it complained about un-declared variables too until I removed the semicolon.

Comment: @Ola That's because SQLfiddle's default batch separator is `;`. You can change that (see the drop-downs under the schema/query windows). This is not really a "fix" because you *will* need to use semi-colons somewhere.

Comment: Q why would you give me bad feed -1 if my Q was valide??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this looks like you are trying to populate a numbers table here is another way to do that. It doesn't use a loop and is quite a bit simpler.

```
DECLARE @max INT;
SET @max = 100000;

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    E5(N) as (select 1 from E4, E1),
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E5
    )

INSERT INTO dbo.Nums 
select N from cteTally
where N <= @max;
```

Comment: Thanks this is helping